# Kendo listview how to show limited htmltext in encoded format?

Tags: listview, kendo-ui

Kendo listview how do you show limited htmltext  in encoded format?

```
<span class="span3">#:Name#</span>  
<div class="span9">**#=HtmlContent#**</div
```

> 

In `#=HtmlContent` I am getting 2000 characters and just want to show 100 characters..How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
<div class="span9">#= HtmlContent.substring(0, 100) #</div>
```

Any JavaScript code can be put inside a Kendo Template. The [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method will return the first 100 characters of the string.And if you want to show html encoded output use #: # instead of #= #:

```
<div class="span9">#: HtmlContent.substring(0, 100) #</div>
```